# Random graphs constructed by many large matchings

Tags: random-graphs, matching-theory, regular-graph

Let $G_{n,d}$ be $d$-regular random graph. We know that for $d \geq 3$, $G \in G_{n,d}$ a.a.s. has a $1$-factorisation when $n$ is even.

So, the resulting graph that obtained from randomly choosing $d$ disjoint perfect matchings is contiguous with $G_{n,d}$.

If we randomly choosing $d$ disjoint matchings of size $(\frac{1}{2}-o(1))n$ , Is there a characterization of the resulting graph distribution?

In particularly, for fixed vertex $v$, we have $Pr(deg(v)=0)\leq o(1)$. Then a.a.s. $deg(v)=d$. And for a vertex set that has constant size, we have all vertex in this set have degree $d$. Furthermore, does resulting graph a.a.s. have a large induced subgraph with large minimum degree?

Comment: What do you do with multiple edges which appear in the union of independent matchings?

Comment: @FedorPetrov We randomly choose disjoint matchings. So there doesn't exist multiple edges.

Comment: So, we consider all sets of $d$ disjoint matchings with equal probability, right? But then how can it be $G_{n,d/2}$, if the degrees may be as large as $d$?

Comment: We can understand it as uniform randomly choosing $d$ disjoint matching from $K_n$. I guess this may be a regular graph in the asymptotic sense（a.a.s.）.

Comment: I do not understand what exactly does it mean that two distributions on graphs coincide a.a.s, would you please elaborate?

Comment: For a graph $G$ and a property $Q$, If $P(G \in Q) \rightarrow 1$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then we say that a graph $G$ a.a.s. satisfies the property $Q$.

Comment: Ok, but it is about determinidtic property $Q$, right?

Comment: Yes. It is a definition.

Comment: Well, but "being a random regular graph" is not a deterministic property.

Comment: The property $Q$ is an intuitive statement, formally, you can also think of it as a collection of graphs. This is also why we say that $P(G\in Q)$. I think "being a random regular graph" is correct.

Comment: Yes, but $G_{n,d}$ is not a collection of graphs, it is a distribution on graphs.

Comment: For example, the resulting graph that obtained from randomly choosing $d$
 disjoint perfect matchings a.a.s. is $G_{n,d}$. We denote the resulting graph  by $G$. First, it is easy to see that $G$ is a $d$-regular graph. Second, $G_{n,d}$ a.a.s. has a 1-factorisation when $n$ is even. So the set of graphs that can be obtained from randomly choosing $d$ disjoint perfect matchings a.a.s. are same as the set of all regular graph.Therefore, the resulting graph distribution  is $G_{n,d}$.

Comment: It is not so simple. If two distributions have the same support, they are not necessarily the same.

Comment: For $G_{n,d}$, we randomly choose a graph from all $d$-regular graph. For our random process, we also randomly choose a graph from all $d$-regular graph (a.a.s.), because every edge is is chosen with equal probability, it is symmetrical.

Comment: We need "every graph is chosen with equal probability", right? Not just "every edge".

Comment: Yes, you are right. By symmetry, we can get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146505/discussion-between-zhukui-bai-and-fedor-petrov).

Comment: The symmetry argument here is not correct. Random regular graphs formed by sampling all regular graphs with equal probability do not have the same asymptotic distribution as random regular graphs made by uniformly choosing disjoint perfect matchings. For example, the expected number of short cycles is different. The reason is that a graph with a large number of 1-factorizations is more likely to be generated than one with a small number of 1-factorizations. However, for constant $d\geq 3$ it has been proved that the distributions are "contiguous". Look for work of N. C. Wormald.

Comment: Thank you! I got it.